# Extract Images from Video with FFMPEG and Insert Into Database

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this FFMPEG command to extra a still from a video every 10 seconds.

```
fmpeg  -i input.mov -vf fps=10  -y %03d-output.jpg;
```

This method will name the files:

001-output.jpg
002-output.jpg

etc.

However, since ffmpeg is creating these rather than a loop, what is the best way to loop through these to add them to a MySQL database?

Comment: What do you mean by, "rather than a loop"? You want to add existing JPG files to a database? Seems more like a mysql question to me.

Comment: When ffmpeg creates the jpgs is does so in one command.  I just mean, if there was a loop where it created each image I could easily just do an insert for each one.  So, I am not sure what the best way to handle this would be.  The insert isn't a problem . It's getting the data for each created image.